# Extract data from square brackets in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

while doing an sql query, i have a field **Gift_Number** which give me the below data

`Gift certificat (-) [2989153053216]`
 Sql Query :

```
           SELECT SUBSTRING(H.F1056, patindex('%[^0]%',H.F1056), 10) AS Shop_Number
                  , '000' AS Cashier_Code
                  , H.F1057 AS Terminal_number
                  , REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), H.F254, 103), '/', '') AS Todays_Date
                  , STIME AS Ticket_Time
                  , H.F1032 AS Ticket_Number
                  , K.F1063 AS Mode_Of_Payment
                  , K.F02 AS Mode_Of_Payment_Desc
                  , CASE WHEN J.F1063 = 117 
                         THEN J.F02 
                         ELSE '' END AS Gift_Number
                  , CASE WHEN I.F02 = 'TOTAL' 
                         THEN I.F65 
                         ELSE 0 END AS Total_Ticket
             FROM [READEJ_H] H
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[READEJ_I] I 
               ON (H.F1101 = I.F1101 AND I.F02 = 'TOTAL')
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[READEJ_I] K 
               ON (H.F1101=K.F1101 AND K.F1063 BETWEEN 100 AND 199)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[READEJ_I] J 
               ON (H.F1101=J.F1101 AND J.F1063 = 117)
            WHERE I.F65  <> CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION,0)
```

How can i extract only the information between the square brackets in the sql select statement.The output should be as below :

```
    2989153053216
```

Comment: Please mention the database.

Comment: also add your query, please

Comment: I am using sql server database

Comment: Also please do some research. This question is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have tried other research but to no avail. RealCheeseLord I have included my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use `charindex` and `substring`:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(100) = 'Gift certificat (-) [2989153053216]'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@S, CHARINDEX('[', @S)+1, CHARINDEX(']', @S) - CHARINDEX('[', @S)-1)
```

Result:  `2989153053216`

However, you should be aware that this will raise an error if the string does not contain the delimiters, or if the `]` delimiter comes before the `[` delimiter.

Comment: It works, the data will always be in the square brakets

Comment: Glad to help :-)